# Updating to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: updates

I have a dual boot operating with win xp. I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04. Since is a 32-bit system. Will I able to update it to Ubuntu 16.04??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Ubuntu 16.04 still includes all its packages for the i386 (32-bit) architecture. Just do a normal release upgrade once the upgrader offers it (once 16.04.1 is released).